# How to use chinese half-width comma in bootstrap-tagsinput?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-tags-input

bootstrap-tagsinput use `keypress` event which not support Chinese characters.

I try [this](https://github.com/liu-dongyu/bootstrap-tagsinput/commit/c4a68f01689f7cba090beb98643b84d7451d88a6) to solve the problem, but it is not a good solution.

Any good ideas?

Comment: You actually use full width characters casually? 你平時用全型字打字? :O

Comment: No,i use half width characters.

Comment: http://keycode.info/ try inputting the full-width comma. It picked up here. That means keypress event should pick up any keyboard presses

Comment: I try inputting chinese characters in [api.jquery.com/keypress/](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/) . Not work in both firefox and chrome.

Comment: That must be because IME doesn't trigger the keypress event